# How do I query certain JSON items using Retrofit?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm using `Retrofit` to collect and parse `JSON` data I created and uploaded to the internet. I can successfully display all the data, but being new to Retrofit I'm struggling to understand how to query and display certain items from the `JSON` data.

I manage to display all the `JSON` data using the `interface`:

```
@GET("d6jww")
Call<List<RetrofitVariables>> findPosts();
```

in the `onResponse()` method of `Retrofit`. But what if I only want to display, let's say, the names, or the id of the `JSON` object. How do I query that?

I tried:

```
@GET("d6jww")
Call<List<RetrofitVariables>> getId(
        @Query( "id" )
                String id);
```

and:

```
@GET("d6jww")
Call<List<RetrofitVariables>> getId(
        @Query("SELECT * FROM id")
                String id);
```

But in my `ViewModel` `Android-Studio` wants me to add an argument when using the `interface`, and I honestly don't know how to use it:

```
public Call<List<RetrofitVariables>> getRepositoryId() {
    return this.repository.getRetrofitRepository().getId( ??? );
}
```

My `JSON` looks like this:

```
[
    {"id":231, "name": "Bob", "date":"3/13/2015",     
    "from":"8:00","until":"13:00"},

    {"id":232, "name": "Joe", "date":"1/3/2015",   
    "from":"12.30","until":"13:00"}
]
```

To summarise my questions:

1. Can I query the `JSON` directly or do I first need to put it in `Room` and query it from there?
2. If I can query `JSON` directly, how do I structure the interface (to collect the names, or id)? And what's with the missing argument?
3. How do I query specific names? Example, if I want to query whether Bob is in the JSON data, how do I set up that interface?

Thanks a bunch in advance :)

Comment: First of all you cannot use `@Query` outside a `@Dao` AFAIK, second you cannot query `JSON`.  I would suggest modeling the data then storing it in Room. Checkout this codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/

Comment: Ah, I suspected as much. So, there is no (good) way to take certain parts directly from the JSON data then? Thanks @christoandrew

Comment: Its not entirely impossible to search the `JSON` but if you want to you can look at https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you would like to do but anyway.

For this:

> 2. If I can query JSON directly, how do I structure the interface (to collect the names, or id)? And what's with the missing argument?

and comment:

> So, there is no (good) way to take certain parts directly from the JSON data then?

You cannot affect what the service  returns but you can choose what you pick. Say you have this kind of DAO normally (the full Post -or is it Person?- data):

```
public class Post {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private String from;
    private String until;
}
```

and normally you might have something like (not necessarli but as an example):

```
@GET("d6jww")
Call<List<Post>> findPosts();
```

To restrict data to only some fields you can declare a new DAO for it. like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class PostId {
    private String id;
}
```

and a new API method pointing the same endpoint:

```
@GET("d6jww")
Call<List<PostId>> getPostIds();
```

But anyway you need to do the filtering on the client side.

Comment: Hehe, thank you for helping out @pirho :) Room, I suppose, is still the way to go :)